# Salesforce Lightning Record Page Information

Tags: lightning-web-components

My Lightning web component is deployed on many custom Lightning pages. Can we get the information inside lwc from where my component is rendered. One way is to pass the Lightning Page Name/Developername as a property in meta file, But wondering if there is some method already to be used directly in LWC to get the custom page information just like 'objectApiName' or 'getObjectInfo' in js

Comment: Did you try checking [meta file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder) ?

Comment: I want the information in .js. I do not want admin to write and pass on as a property to my LWC since its error prone

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include your exact requirement as its not clear